# Fourier spectrum reflected across origin and Nyquist frequency

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

Recently I've been trying to figure out what's the point of negative frequencies produced by the fourier transform. One answer was it's just there to make calculations more elegant. It could be anything on the negative part of the $w$ axis, but we've chosen to make it an even function. If we used fourier sine transform for example, there would be no negative frequency values at all.
Now recall what Nyqist-Shannon theorem says about what's the necessary minimum sampling frequency to avoid aliasing. It has to be at least twice as big as the maximum frequency present in sampled signal.

What if we got rid of the negative frequencies? We would only have only the positive ones that make any sense. [image]

Now in b) we can sample at frequency $f_s = B$ and avoid aliasing, because we don't have the negative frequencies that would cause aliasing. So we can sample the signal at 2 times higher frequency than it's possible with presence of negative frequencies in a).

Could you please tell me at which point my reasoning is wrong here? What's the motivation for having a fourier spectrum of a signal satisfy $X(f)=X(-f)$?

Comment: Loosely, there is a collection of functions that are used to characterize the behaviour of $t \mapsto f(t)$. The usual choice in this context are the functions $t \mapsto e^{i \omega t}$, less usually are the functions $t \mapsto \cos (\omega t), t \mapsto \sin (\omega t)$. Using one function with 'negative' frequency (I think of it as an index rather than a negative) is more convenient that pairs of functions with non-negative frequencies. The bandwidth is a measure of the number of such functions needed to represent the signal. That, at some level, doesn't change with representation.

Comment: My point being that you can't just magically 'get rid of' the negative frequencies.

Comment: What can you tell about [twistor's answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46948/what-is-the-significance-of-negative-frequency-in-fourier-transform)? "you can, if you wish, avoid negative frequencies by using the Fourier Sine Transform".

Comment: Well, that was my point above. Either you have some $\omega \mapsto \hat{f}(\omega)$ defined on the reals (that is, including the negative axis) or you have $\omega \mapsto \hat{f}_c(\omega)$, $\omega \mapsto \hat{f}_s(\omega)$ defined on the non negative half line. You have twice the content on half the line. Nothing has disappeared. (I'm talking about real valued 'time domain' signals here.)

Comment: So I can get rid of negative frequencies. I don't get how that's not enough for me to use $0,5$ of my original minimum sampling frequency without aliasing.

Comment: I don't have the time to properly address the issues you bring up (and there are many). The main one is that the method of analysis doesn't affect the signal, of course, so you can't magically make the negative frequencies go away. In radio broadcast, one can reduce the bandspread of a signal around the carrier by using a technique called single sideband transmission, but with this technique you are changing the signal.

Comment: As an aside, I think this is a good question as it brings up much of the loose thinking that is taught in signal processing courses. The underlying concept is the Poisson summation formula which (loosely) shows that the spectrum of a uniformly sampled signal is the sum of the spectra of the original signal shifted by ${k \over T}$, where $T$ is the sampling interval.

Comment: Note that when we talk about the bandwidth of a signal as you have above, it really refers to half of the spectrum of the signal. Any real signal has $\overline{\hat{f}(\omega)} = \hat{f}(-\omega)$, so the Nyquist criterion gives a sufficient condition to avoid overlap.

Comment: You can express the Poisson summation formula using the $\cos,\sin$ formulation, but it will end up giving the same sufficient condition.

Comment: You are correct that the sampling frequency need only meet the bandwidth in order to accurately sample a signal. This will prevent fold-over aliasing, from which there is no recovery. The other type of aliasing just results in a shift of the signal, which is easily accounted for or corrected. As for the negative frequencies, I don't understand your question. There is no motivation for having $X(f) = X^\ast (-f)$, that's just a property of real signals. However, not all signals have this property.

Comment: All I'm saying is we don't need negative frequencies. They are just an artifical mathematical construct that doesn't provide us with any additional valuable information. And it's a limitation for us to have those frequencies, because they cause aliasing at sampling frequency $f_s < 2B$. If we get rid of them, we could sample at $f_B$ and get no aliasing - image b).

Comment: Why are you (if you are) assuming you have a real signal?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @user4205580 because you need the complete spectum to reconstruct a complex signal. Consider the discreet FT of a sample of length n, for a complex signal this is 2n real degrees of freedom. The finite FT of such a signal has n complex values, and so 2n real values, all of which are needed to reconstruct the original signal (and there is no symmetry to call on). Also in the real world we often/usually dealing with complex signals all of the time.

Comment: @user4205580 Negative frequencies are very useful and can provide very valuable information. [Here](http://www.ee.nmt.edu/~elosery/lectures/Quadrature_signals.pdf) is an intro that should help shed some light on the topic.

Comment: @ConradTurner, so if we had only real signals, the Nyquist frequency would be $f_s$ instead of $f_s/2$ - like on picture b)?

Comment: @user4205580 The Nyquist frequency is what it is. Are you asking can you construct the non-negative part of the spectrum with half the number of sample points implied by Nyquist sampling, I doubt it as you already have 1/2 the number of real degrees of freedom compared to a complex signal.